# Temperature log with acpi -t

Tags: linux, freeze, logging, temperature

I had system freezes with my HP Pavilion when using Linux (at the moment I use Debian, Ubuntu showed the same behavior). HP support forum suggests that the error is related to temperature control. So I would like to log the temperature output with `aspi -t` while waiting for the next freeze.

My first try was:

```
$ acpi -t > temperaturelog.txt
$ watch -n 1 acpi -t >> temperaturelog.txt
```

However, this leads to only two lines, the second command leads to a cryptic second line. It might be because I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end the logging. What did I do wrong? How would you improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to log temperatures every second:

```
$ while true; do echo `date` '->' `acpi -t`>> temperaturelog.txt;sleep 1;done
```

You'll have to kill or Ctrl-C to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have the same problem, I wrote a really simple and small python script which logs the temperature to a file.
I also wrote a little script which can plot the temperature data and possible system shutdowns to a graph.

You can get the two python scripts here: https://github.com/tymm/temp-log

I hope it helps.